# Make Servicestack's FacebookAuthProvider return AuthResponse

Tags: c#, api, rest, servicestack

Is it possible to make ServiceStack's FacebookAuthProvider return AuthResponse instead of always returning HttpWebResponse.
I've tried creating my own CustomFacebookAuthProvider and overriding Authenticate method. But no matter what i try, i can't make it return a AuthResponse.

Is it even possible?

I tried this:

```
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request)
{
    var tokens = Init(authService, ref session, request);

    var code = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().QueryString["code"];
    var isPreAuthCallback = !code.IsNullOrEmpty();
    if (!isPreAuthCallback)
    {
        var preAuthUrl = PreAuthUrl + "?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}"
            .Fmt(AppId, this.CallbackUrl.UrlEncode(), string.Join(",", Permissions));

        authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        return authService.Redirect(preAuthUrl);
    }

    var accessTokenUrl = this.AccessTokenUrl + "?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}"
        .Fmt(AppId, this.CallbackUrl.UrlEncode(), AppSecret, code);

    HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    var statusDescription = string.Empty;
    var stackTrace = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var contents = accessTokenUrl.GetStringFromUrl();
        var authInfo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(contents);
        tokens.AccessTokenSecret = authInfo["access_token"];
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;
        authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo.ToDictionary());

        return new CustomAuthResponse
                   {
                       ReferrerUrl = session.ReferrerUrl,
                       ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus(),
                       SessionId = session.Id,
                       UserName = session.UserName
                   };
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
        statusDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusDescription;
        stackTrace = we.StackTrace;

        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            statusDescription = "AccessTokenFailed";
    }

    return new CustomAuthResponse
    {
        ReferrerUrl = session.ReferrerUrl,
        ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus
        {
            ErrorCode = statusCode.ToString(),
            Message = statusDescription,
            StackTrace = stackTrace
        },
        SessionId = session.Id,
        UserName = session.UserName
    };
}
```

Comment: What i mean is, when using FacebookAuthprovider, the Response to the client is Always HttpWebResponseWrapper. Probably because of the roundtrip to facebook.com.

It is this response i need to make my own serializable custom response, so my clients can retrieve a correct json format response.

The HttpResponseWrapper is not serializable.